# why should get_tail() use the lock on tail_mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
template<typename T>
class threadsafe_queue
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        std::shared_ptr<T> data;
        std::unique_ptr<node> next;
    };

    std::mutex head_mutex;
    std::unique_ptr<node> head;
    std::mutex tail_mutex;
    node* tail;

    node* get_tail()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> tail_lock(tail_mutex);
        return tail;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<node> pop_head()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> head_lock(head_mutex);
        // is it necessary to use get_tail()
        if(head.get()==get_tail()) 
        {
            return nullptr;
        }
        std::unique_ptr<node> const old_head=std::move(head);
        head=std::move(old_head->next);
        return old_head;
    }


public:
    threadsafe_queue():
        head(new node),tail(head.get())
    {}

    threadsafe_queue(const threadsafe_queue& other)=delete;
    threadsafe_queue& operator=(const threadsafe_queue& other)=delete;

    std::shared_ptr<T> try_pop()
    {
        std::unique_ptr<node> old_head=pop_head();
        return old_head?old_head->data:std::shared_ptr<T>();
    }

    void push(T new_value)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<T> new_data(
            std::make_shared<T>(std::move(new_value)));
        std::unique_ptr<node> p(new node);
        node* const new_tail=p.get();
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> tail_lock(tail_mutex);
        tail->data=new_data;
        tail->next=std::move(p);
        tail=new_tail;
    }
};
```

Above code is excerpt from "C++ Concurrency in action" on page 162. Here it uses `get_tail()` to get the tail with lock on `tail_mutex`.

The book says:

> It turns out that not only is the lock on `tail_mutex` necessary to protect the read of tail itself, but it’s also necessary to ensure that you don’t get a data race reading the data from the head. If you didn’t have that mutex, it would be quite possible for a thread to call `try_pop()` and a thread to call `push()` concurrently, and there’d be no defined ordering on their operations. Even though each member function holds a lock on a mutex, they hold locks on different mutexes, and they potentially access the same data; all data in the queue originates from a call to `push()`, after all. Because the threads would be potentially accessing the same data without a defined ordering, this would be a data race and undefined behavior. Thankfully the lock on the `tail_mutex` in `get_tail()` solves everything. Because the call to `get_tail()` locks the same mutex as the call to `push()`, there’s a defined order between the two calls. Either the call to `get_tail()` occurs before the call to `push()`, in which case it sees the old value of tail, or it occurs after the call to `push()`, in which case it sees the new value of tail and the new data attached to the previous value of tail.

I don't understand this very well: if i just use `head.get() == tail`, this comparison either happens before `tail = new_tail` in `push()` to compare `head.get()` with the old value of `tail` or after to compare `head.get()` with the new value of `tail`, why would there be a data race?

Comment: `if i just use head.get() == tail, this comparison either happens before tail = new_tail in push() to compare head.get() with the old value of tail or after to compare head.get() with the new value of tail, why would there be a data race?` - This is data race **by definition**: *accessing same variable* (`tail`) *concurrently* (by `push()` and `get_tail()` methods) and one access (by `push()`) is *write access*. Using `tail_mutex` in `get_tail()` method eliminates this concurrency and other problems, described in the given cite in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not agree with this. `get_tail` should not have any mutexes in it, this function on it's own is not data-race prone, nor it is memory reorder prone. In fact, `get_tail` should be eliminated altogether. Users of the the tail should protect the usage as approriate, but putting mutex inside get tail is in fact a terrible antipattern. Putting mutex in every function of course is going to make your programm thread safe. It will also make it effectively single-threaded - and if single-threaded is desired, simply do not use threads.

The art of multithreading is not in putting mutexes everywhere. It is in NOT using them.

Comment: thanks for asking, i'm sorry for the late acceptance